# How to mimic sound of a trumpet in English?

Tags: word-request, onomatopoeia

How to mimic trumpet sound in English?

I expect something like:

> Too-too-too-too-toooooom!
>
> Too-too-too-toom!
>
> Too-too-too-toooooo-toooooo-toom!

Is it correct?

Comment: I don't know if there's a standard [onomatopoeia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Onomatopoeia) word for trumpets.... sometimes _toot_ is used for horns.

Comment: Depending not the pitch of your trumpet, "brrr brrr brrr" can also be used, but may be confused with being cold ("brrrr") if not sounded correctly...

Answer (score 4):

In *The Pirates of Penzance* W.S. Gilbert certainly thought there was [an onomatopoeic description of a trumpet](http://www.gilbertandsullivanarchive.org/pirates/web_op/pirates16.html):

> **Sergeant**.
>   There is nothing brings it round
>   Like the trumpet’s martial sound,
>   Like the trumpet’s martial sound
>
> **Sergeant & Police.**
>   Tarantara! tarantara!
>   Tarantara! tarantara!
>   Tarantara! tarantara!
>   Tarantara! tarantara!
>   Tarantara! tarantara!
>   Tarantara! tarantara!
>   Tarantara, ra, ra,
>   Tarantara!  Ra, ra, ra, ra,
>   Ra, ra, ra, ra,
>   Ra, ra, ra, ra,
>   Ra, ra, ra, ra,
>   Ra, ra, ra, ra,
>   Tarantara, ra, ra,

Your mileage may vary, and this is only one man's usage (though an important one). I think it's safe to say that in this case you're entitled to use whatever sounds right to you.

Comment: [*Any writer who can slyly work history into his narratives without the **tootling of trumpets**, the raising of showy curtains and the heroic yawning of readers is to be commended.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22tootling+of+trumpets%22)

Comment: That remindes me of _The Pink Panther Sheet Music_.

Comment: I honestly never realized "Tarantara" was supposed to be the sound of a trumpet.

Comment: @JamieB: The Sergeant (solo singer) asserts that there is "nothing like the trumpet's martial sound" and then with the chorus makes that sound. I don't know how it could be any plainer.

Answer (score 1):

I play trumpet. The way we tend to tongue our notes is with "dah" if that helps.

however, the "dah" doesn't really come out. If you listen to a great brass player, it sounds brilliant, but the beginning isn't very pronounced. a hard consonant can't correctly represent it. Also, the noise tends to be very clean.

Try "Rhaaaa"

Comment: Isn't the name "trumpet" somewhat onomatopoeic, "truh... truh... trumpet"?